# How do I access other users calendars with google calendar v3?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-apps, google-oauth

I am using the Google Calendar (v3) API, with google apps and am wanting to use a single oauth2 credential to determine what users are free/busy at any given point.

I am wanting to use this:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query

But to use this I need to get all the calendar ids for all the users. I cannot do this as the java client for the google calendar can only retrieve calendars of the user who owns the credential.

Note: I have access to all the users through the provisioning api.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am totally blocked by this.

Answer (score 7):

For primary calendars, the calendarId is the user's email address. The authenticated user will also need to have permission to access the calendar. If you're using the Provisioning API then I'll assume you are a super admin, and super admins can access every calendar on their domain.

The specific query you are trying to do takes a list of calendarIds to query as a JSON list. If you are only concerned about primary calendars, then set each user's email as an id like this:

```
"items": [
  {
    "id": "user1@example.com"
  },
  {
    "id": "user2@example.com"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

In 2013, I took about a week to integrate with Google Calendar.

There were several steps:

1. ESTABLISH CREDENTIALS
2. GET CALENDAR OWNER AUTHORIZATION
3. RETRIEVE AUTHORIZATION CODE
4. REQUEST TOKEN
5. RETRIEVE TOKEN
6. GET CALENDAR ID
7. UPDATE THE TOKEN
8. RETRIEVE CALENDAR ENTRIES

I described the steps in more detail in 2013, now web archived here: https://web.archive.org/web/20130215064337/http://www.tqis.com/eloquency/googlecalendar.htm#DOC77

Comment: The link returns a 404

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20130215064337/http://www.tqis.com/eloquency/googlecalendar.htm#DOC77