# Access Google calendar of my users

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I need to manage Google calendars of my site users, I mean to view, add and remove meetings from my site backed in calendars of my site users with their customers. 
I've looked through Google documentation and couldn't understand what is the best flow. 
Is the following would be right thing to do?

1. I create service Google account
2. All my users share their calendars with my service account
3. My site back-end manages users calendar using my service account.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

**1.Delegate calendar access**
To delegate your calendar: [See Here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/117596?hl=en)

**2.
Google Calendar
for Administrative Assistants : If you directly manage others’ calendars, this is the Google Calendar guide for you.**[Read Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mRFEgCWIFbFz2v_L0odlI1oIDyOZESBrGFJm7Sun15Y/edit)

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. I need to access the users calendars programmatically. The links you shared describe "human" flow. What will be the API flow?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/) wherein it discussed the basic concept of how each calendar user is associated with a primary calendar and a number of other calendars that they can also access. If you want to access the primary calendar of the currently logged in user, use the `primary` keyword.

Here are some related SO threads which might help:

- [Can I access other Google User's Calendars through the Google API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21655774/can-i-access-other-google-users-calendars-through-the-google-api-v3)

> OAuth 2.0 service accounts are the proper method for accessing user
>   accounts:
>
> https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount
>
> You need to grant the service account client id access to the
>   necessary Calendar API scopes:
>
> https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account
>
> Then your service account can impersonate your users and perform
>   calendar operations on their behalf:
>
> https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation#instantiate_a_drive_service_object
>
> These docs describe Google Drive but the process for Calendar is
>   identical.

- [How do I access other users calendars with google calendar v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359249/how-do-i-access-other-users-calendars-with-google-calendar-v3)

Hope this helps!